# Code is redirecting visitor to homepage no matter what link is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, jsonp

I have a website and would like to redirect visitors from different countries to an URL-Path. For this purpose, I use the code below. The problem with this code is that it always redirects you to the same URL, no matter what link you click on the page. What am I missing?

```
    <!-- IP REDIRECTING -->
<script>
// Geolocation Redirect
let eng_list = ['BE', 'DK', 'FI', 'FR', 'IS', 'IT', 'HR', 'NL', 'RO', 'SK', 'HU', 'BG', 'GR', 'IE', 'GB', 'CA', 'LU', 'NO', 'PL', 'SE', 'RS', 'CZ', 'TR', 'US', 'AL', 'EE', 'LV', 'LT', 'MK', 'PT', 'SM', 'ES',  'IC', 'EA'];
let presentUrl = location.href;
let targetUrl = "https://www.homepage.de/en";
// Getting the country code from the user's IP
  if (presentUrl != targetUrl) {
$.getJSON('https://ipinfo.io/json', function(data) {
  if (eng_list.includes(data.country)) {
    location.href = "https://www.homepage.de/en";
  }
}, "jsonp");};
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "no matter what link you click on"?    Your code runs on page load and works as expected.  If doesn't modify any links on a page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line in the `if` always redirects to the English "subdomain" as you have it hard coded as such via this line:

```
location.href = "https://www.homepage.de/en";
```

Though this not really a "subdomain" but is besides the point. If you want to make it so different languages are actually applied then you need to remove the hardcoding to `/en` and make that part "vary" based on the conditions needed.

Comment: I'll edit the question, since it's more a path then a subdomain. 
I somehow understand what you mean but changing the variable to /en didn't kinda worked either.
My problem is, if you visit the page and click on any link of the page it will redirect you to the homepage with the path addition.

This script is added to the body of my theme.liquid. (shopify theme).